# how to add a condition before attaching a file in a shell script in unix?

Tags: shell, unix

```
cd $TGTDIR
count1=`cat File1.csv | wc -l`
count2=`cat File2.csv | wc -l`
(echo "Exceptions/Reports "; 
if [ $count1 -gt 0 ]; then uuencode File1.csv File1.csv fi
if [ $count2 -gt 1 ]; then uuencode File2.csv File2.csv fi )
| mailx -s " $WORKFLOW_NAME was successful at $Datetime. " $MAIL_USER
```

The above code is not running and showing a syntax error for missing ')'.
Can anyone tell me how to add an **if condition** just before attaching a file in unix shell script.

Comment: you probably need an \ at the end of the line starting with `(`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
count1=`cat ~/File1.txt | wc -l`
count2=`cat ~/File2.txt | wc -l`
echo "Exceptions/Reports " 
  $(
     if [[ $count1 -gt 0 ]]; then 
        uuencode ~/File1.txt File1.txt
     elif [[ $count2 -gt 1 ]]; then 
        uuencode ~/File2.txt File2.txt 
     fi
   ) | mail -s "I was successful at $(date)." your@gmail.com
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Actually there two different if conditions. Its not a nested if. Secondly, the below code is just working fine.       cd $TGTDIR
count1=`cat File1.csv | wc -l`
count2=`cat File2.csv | wc -l`
(echo "Exceptions/Reports "; 
uuencode File1.csv File1.csv 
uuencode File2.csv File2.csv )
| mailx -s " $WORKFLOW_NAME was successful at $Datetime. " $MAIL_USER

Answer (score 0):

Seems, the Unix server that I am working on is older version and there were some syntax errors:

cd $TGTDIR
count1=`cat File1.csv | wc -l`
count2=`cat File2.csv | wc -l`
(echo "Exceptions/Reports ";
if [ $count1 -gt 0 ] then uuencode File1.csv File1.csv fi
if [ $count2 -gt 1 ] then uuencode File2.csv File2.csv fi ) | mailx -s " $WORKFLOW_NAME was successful at $Datetime. " $MAIL_USER

*NO semi colon after if
*the chunk of **| mailx -s** should be just after the ')' bracket in the same line

Thank you for answering the question. :)